# Core data/Database Entity relationships

Tags: database-design, core-data

If two entities exist and in one sense they have a one to many relationship and in another sense they have a many to one relationship. Do these 2 relationships become a many to many or is it ok to have 2 relationships? One to many, Many to one?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: Many photos can have a GPSLocation, Many GPSLocations can have a photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a one-to-many relationship, given your example - depending on which side of the relationship you start from it's one-to-many (GPS location -> photo) or many-to-one (photo -> GPS location) - this doesn't make it a many-to-many, though!

A photo has one-and-only-one GPS location, so your tables would look like this...

```
PHOTO

ID
GPSLocationID
...

GPSLOCATION

ID
LAT
LONG
...
```

Comment: Your answer was so good it made the other poster delete all his traces on this post.

Comment: :) - no, I think the other poster had answered prior to getting the example clarifying the situation, Helium3.

Answer (score 1):

In ER modelling it is quite normal and permissable for two entity types to have more than one relatiomship between them.